# Custom error pages in ASP.Net MVC retaining url, without redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

If I go to my mvc site and hit a non-existant url:

```
/secretsauce
```

I want to...:

- NOT do any redirects, ie url in browser is stil /secretsauce
- Return a 404 error
- Display a custom error page, preferably an actionresult of a custom ErrorController (so I can do clever stuff on the error page), not just a static HTML file or an ASPX file

Is this even possible? If so, how?

And if yes, is it possible for it to work both while debugging in VS or will it only work when hosted in IIS/Azure?

Comment: https://blog.dmbcllc.com/aspnet-application_error-detecting-404s/

Comment: @Grizzly Ironically that page now returns a 404. :D